# Weird JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Here's my code, where AttrDict is an attributive dictionary. I also parsed my json to an online validator and it said it's ok.

```
available_langs = AttrDict({})

# Language import
for translation in os.listdir('translations'):
    try:
        if translation.split('.')[1] == 'json':
            lang = translation.split('.')[0]
            with open(f'translations/{translation}', 'r') as f:
                print(f.read())
                available_langs[lang] = load(f)
    except IndexError:
        pass

print(available_langs)
```

And here's eng.json that it tries to parse

```
{
    "start": {
        "text": "Hello there!", 
        "markup": [{"start_picking": "Start picking"}, {"settings": "Settings"}]
    },
    "loading": {
        "text": "Loading...",
        "markup": null
    }
}
```

And I get

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

By reading the file

```
print(f.read())
```

You are moving the file pointer to the end of the file, so there's nothing for `json.load` to read.

You could reset the file pointer

```
f.seek(0)
```

or just don't `read` the file

or read the file and deserialise the data from the resulting string using `json.loads`

```
with open(f'translations/{translation}', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(data)
    available_langs[lang] = json.loads(data)
```

**Demonstration**

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> import json

>>> with open('foo.json', 'w') as f:
...     json.dump(d, f)
... 
>>> with open('foo.json') as f:
...     f.read()
...     json.load(f)
... 
'{"a": 1}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>>>
```

Comment: It changes nothing. f.read() doesn't impact the file I read because i didn't write f = f.read()

Comment: `f.read()` moves the file pointer from the beginning of the file to the end.  Without resetting the pointer, further attempts to read the file, including json.load, will start from the end of the file and read nothing

Comment: The only other possibility is that the file is empty, which I assume you have disproved by having printed the result of reading from it?  Unless it's being emptied or overwritten elsewhere in the code.